# How do I disable the LEDs on a Nighthawk R7000 running DD-WRT?

Tags: dd-wrt

My Netgear Nighthawk R7000 is running DD-WRT. Since it is in my bedroom, I would like to disable all the LEDs. How can I do that?

NOTE: I flashed my R7000 with the instructions available [here](http://www.desipro.de/ddwrt-ren/K3-AC-Arm/Readme) and [this firmware](http://www.desipro.de/ddwrt-ren/K3-AC-Arm/Initial/).

Comment: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Useful_Scripts#LED_Scripts  This may help I have the Same Router with DDWRT on it. I will test these out when i get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using information available [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=906392), I could disable the LEDs with the following commands (run over telnet):

```
$ for i in 2 3 8 9 12 13 17 18; do gpio enable $i; done

$ for i in 14 15; do gpio disable $i; done
```